# eclipse juno/m2e maven builder missing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, m2eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using eclipse juno with m2e plugin. Is there any possibility to trigger a maven goal when build all [ctrl+B] is triggered from eclipse.
More over maven builder is unable to edit

Comment: Sorry, but I’m not sure what your actual question is. Could you please rephrase your question or provide more details?

Comment: @Chriki Question has been rephrased hope you will understand it better now

Comment: Do you just want to run an arbitrary Maven goal or are you actually missing a certain goal which is already attached to a phase in your Maven build lifecycle? In other words: is the required goal automatically run by Maven when you run for example `mvn package` (or should the goal be run then)?

Comment: @Chriki Since my workspace includes both maven and non maven projects where my non maven projects depends upon the maven project. I need to trigger the maven build so that non maven projects will get its dependency. I need this to be done when ever I build my workspace

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an `ant` script to be run when each project is built which could call maven.

In the Project Properties select `Builders` click `New...` and select `Ant Builder` you can then configure the ant script and select targets to be run for Auto Build (build all), clean and manual build.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do the same with maven builders